# Pass JSON to JS using Django render

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

In my views.py file, I have the following dictionary:

```
data = {'pk': '1980.24', 'model': 'artworks.metaData', 'fields': {'medium': 'Oil on canvas ', 'description': 'missing', 'credit': 'Gift of Nicholas Wyeth, 1980 ', 'collection': 2, 'height': '21.7', 'culture': 'Missing value', 'depictedPeople': 'missing', 'creation_date': '1896 ', 'account': 'n/a', 'original_url': 'http://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/10738?sortBy=Relevance&amp;what=Canvas%7cOil+paintings&amp;ao=on&amp;ft=*&amp;offset=0&amp;rpp=100&amp;pos=1', 'url': 'annotatie01.io.tudelft.nl/collections/Metropolitan/1980.24.jpg', 'title': 'Gooseberries ', 'object_number': '1980.24', 'width': '35.7', 'artist': 'Joseph Decker '}}
```

I wish to be able to use/access this dictionary on my webpage.

**My attempts:**

I tried to send data using the render in my views.py,

```
def foo():
    context = {'data':data}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

to access it using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var received_data  = "{{data}}";
</script>
```

Using this, data is transmitted, but it's garbled:

```
"{&#39;pk&#39;: &#39;1980.24&#39;, &#39;model&#39;: &#39;artworks.metaData&#39;, &#39;fields&#39;: {&#39;medium&#39;: &#39;Oil on canvas &#39;, &#39;descripti...etc
```

I tried using `json.dumps(data)` and `JSON.parse(received_data )` but this raised an error:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1.
```

**In short**:

How can I send JSON data from Py to JS using Django Render()?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

simplest way will be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var received_data  = "{{ data|safe }}";
</script>
```

**Security warning**.
`json.dumps` does not escape forward slashes: an attack is `{'</script><script>alert(123);</script>': ''}`

Comment: What is the function of the | operator? A name would be okay, so i look for the documentation.

Comment: its not a name bro. try to find for django template filters and you will find you can use filters after the pipe sign | with variables

Comment: @Exprator I added a security warning as this method is unsafe. The escaping rules for json.dumps do not 100% match those used in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to convert your dict into a string for django 1.5+ do :

```
import json

def foo():
    js_data = json.dumps(data)
    render_template_to_response("imageView/index.html", {"data": js_data})
```

In `imageView/index.html` keep:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var received_data = "{{data|safe}}";
    console.log(received_data);
</script>
```

Else do:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

def foo():
    js_data = simplejson.dumps(data)
    render_template_to_response("imageView/index.html", {"data": js_data})
```

In `imageView/index.html` keep:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var received_data = "{{data}}";
    console.log(received_data);
</script>
```

Comment: It seems like simplejson was removed after  Django V1.5. Should've added my own version number.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the Django {{data}} to a raw JS String in order to prevent JS encoding/decoding problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let received_data  = String.raw`{{ data|safe }}`;
</script>
```